# What's the difference between hay, and stick bundles for beneficial insects?

Tags: insects

I can easily get hay, because my neighbor mows the ditches near me, so I was wondering what exactly the difference between using hay (keeps grass down) for cover, and a pile of sticks for cover is.

Specifically what beneficial insects will live in:
a pile of sticks
hay
pine needles

Comment: What's your question title got to do with the body of the question ?

Comment: the question is about what will live in what location more likely.

Comment: Hi Black, I think you must edit your question and its title.

Answer (score -1):

You don't want hay.  Hay is food for animals and includes all the seeds.  If you use that as a cover, the seeds from the hay will propagate and you'll actually be seeding the grass.  You should use straw instead.

Comment: The grass is already seeded, and I just want to keep it down until the blueberry bushes get big.